# How to convert the output of a script

Tags: python

I am creating a Twitter Bot. I have written a script that will generate text. I am attempting to take the generated text and run it through another script that posts a tweet with the generated text. However, I don't know how to get output of the generate-text-script in a string format.

Here is the code:

```
from textgenrnn import textgenrnn
t = textgenrnn('textgenrnn_weights.HDF5')
text = t.generate(1, temperature=.5)
print(text)
```

Here is the output in Shell:

[image: Shell Capture]

Comment: If it is printing, it is capable of being put into a string format. You can explicitly duck type it to a string by calling `str(text)` though

Comment: When i use str(text), it returns None.

Answer (score 0):

From the textgenrnn documentation, the `generate` function has a `return_as_list` argument which defaults to false, printing the result to the console.

If you want the results as a list of strings, call it like this:

```
output = t.generate(1, temperature=.5, return_as_list=True)
for string in output:
   print(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use stderr redirects to send all the initial info to null, so you are only left with the printed output.

e.g. run your script like `python myscript.py 2>/dev/null`

edit: Combine this with the other answer about using `return_as_list=True` and only print text[0] and I think you have the output you need.

e.g:

```
from textgenrnn import textgenrnn
t = textgenrnn('reddit_rarepuppers_politics.hdf5')
text = t.generate(1, temperature=.5, return_as_list=True)
print(text[0])
```